# How can I use Bluetooth and wired earphones at the same time?

Tags: audio, headphones

I have a Bluetooth earphone and a wired earphone. I want to use them simultaneously.

Is there an app for that? If not, what can I do about it?

Comment: Old, but I am interested in knowing why.  Often that helps in people come up with solutions